# Why do people in various professions like software engineering and management tend to use the word "finalize" instead of "finish"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

As per title of the question, I see this a lot.

"We will release the product when issue 51 has been finalized."
"We are waiting for it to be finalized."

Is this just a case of people trying to sound professional with corporate jargon
, or is there a real difference between 'finish' and 'finalize'?

Comment: Speaking as a software developer, nothing is ever truly *finished* to the point where there’s no more work to do; there are always features to add or bugs to fix.

Comment: @JohnBode Exactly, we don't finish anything, but we can point to one version being the final (last) one that will be produced.

Comment: It's always a safe starting hypothesis that such things are an attempt by the writer/speaker to sound smarter than they really are.  I find the similar pair "utilize" instead of "use" to be precisely that, 99% of the time.  In that last 1% there are shades of meaning that "utilize" properly conveys that "use" does not; the answers here are about that last 1%, not the 99% who probably couldn't explain a difference between "finalize" and "finish" if you asked them.

Comment: `finalize` is also a function/method in some languages (e.g., Java) that indicates an object is no longer in use. It's possible that it might have crept into wider usage by technical folk due to that.

Comment: Completion date? guh, when its done...

Comment: [Done done](https://chrislema.com/what-is-done-done/)

Comment: @JohnBode You surely meant features to fix and bugs to add, right?

Comment: @Steve And if it turns out it isn't done afterall then it's Dun dun duuuuun.

Comment: There's a huge amount of management jargon. You don't "do" things, you "action" them. You don't "work with" other companies, you "partner" them. The list goes on.

Comment: Off topic? How is this different to the English utilize/use question?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The definitions of [finalise](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/finalize) and [finish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/finish) are pretty similar, with *finalise* referring to the production of, or agreement on, the *finished* version.

The single word *finalise* carries the connotation of just the last bit, whereas *finish* needs helper words to carry that connotation (e.g. finish *off*, finish *up*). Saying that something is *finished* can also carry the unwanted sense that it is done for, that is, that it is of no further use; *finalise* doesn't carry that unwanted sense.

In commerce (including the fields of software engineering and management that you specifically referenced), completion isn't always enough. The customer wants confirmation of completion. Transacting parties want the signed agreement that follows the completion of negotiations, or the invoicing and payment that follow the completion of work. So it isn't enough that the work is *finished* (even in the positive sense); it needs to be *finalised*.

Comment: Oooh. That's fascinating. The 'done for' connotation didn't even occur to me.

Comment: +1 Finalization is also a word.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker and a programmer, I also perceive another difference in connotation or referent. "Finalize" often refers to things like plans. Work *begins* when plans are finalized. To say that a plan is "finished" might suggest that the work is done.

Comment: When a ship or airplane is built, there are "acceptance trials" performed by the buyer, generally with manufacturer representation on hand to document (and where possible correct) all deficiencies.  Those deficiencies are checked off, and additional trials performed,  and eventually the vessel gets a clean trial and is formally accepted by the buyer.  Prior to that, the manufacturer still owns it, in every sense of the word.

Comment: In programming, as well, sometimes you have to call it done and kick it out the door even if there is more work that could be done to improve things.  "finalize" carries the connotation that it is the point where someone drew a line and said "we're stopping here, at least for now, and tossing out a release" rather than the point when all possible applicable work had been competed.

Comment: Can you guys please complain to the mods on my behalf? How is this question being deemed off topic? Thanks to you, I and others have learnt important connotations I / we could not have otherwise learned!

Comment: Hi @Sentinel. Your post is on hold and not closed. The reason given was "lack of research", which I think you can rectify by editing in a few dictionary definitions. Your question would then go into a review queue for reopening. I think "lack of research" was originally intended to prevent the site from being a simple dictionary-lookup service or 'do my homework' service. The broader reason is that sometimes it can be difficult for the community to know how much the question asker already knows. Spelling it out in the question helps the community jump straight to the main issue.

Comment: @Sentinel Ping me once you've added the dictionary definitions (let me know if you'd like some help with that), and I'll vote to reopen the question if the reopening hasn't yet been *finalised*. :)

Answer (score 13):

"Finished" refers to an activity or action. You've finished *doing* something.

But "finalised" refers to the state of an object to which all pending modifications have been applied, and no more are necessary/permitted.

So strictly speaking it does not make sense for a *thing* to be finished, though admittedly in English we do sometimes use "I have finished [X]" to mean "I have finished *creating* [X]", if only colloquially. Similarly, "[X] is finished" might informally mean "the creator of [X] has finished their task".

I can't speak for other professions, but in software engineering I guess we try to avoid such ambiguities, at least when constructing programming languages with keywords like `Finalize`.

Answer (score 10):

I suppose they would argue that one ***finishes*** something of a fixed and prescribed nature - such as a 100 metre race.

But where the nature of the task is indeterminable at the outset and could take unexpected twists and turns, such as designing some new software, then it becomes inappropriate to talk of "finishing".

What, someone might ask, do you mean by "finishing"?

***Finalise*** carries the sense of something being declared ended.

However, I also feel there may be an element of that which you refer to in the question - "finalise" sounds more managerially sophisticated than plain old "finish".

Comment: That's also a very good point. Finalising could mean "declared done" according to some kind of consensus.

Answer (score 3):

As a software developer, I find that we use "`finalized`" to mean fully defined ***and***  agreed upon/signed off, not to mean implemented.

"`Done`" has come into vogue with agile/scrum. See ['definition of "done"'](https://manifesto.co.uk/definition-done/).

And I don't really hear "`finished`" as in "**x** is finished", only in the informal "have you finished **x** yet?".

Comment: The OP cites two different contexts: software engineering and management. I have been fascinated by the responses here of the software engineers. Fair enough! But outside that profession, 'finalise' tends to be good old-fashioned management-speak, high-flown words used with the intention of showing that the user is more intelligent than he really is, and hence has  none of the sophistication claimed by the software engineers.

Comment: What is being "finalized" in this context is the specification of what the final product's features should be.  It is at this point that the work of actually realizing that product begins.

Answer (score 0):

"finishing" means reaching the end of some process, "finalizing" means *declaring* the end of some process.  After *finishing*, nothing *needs* to be done any more, after *finalizing*, nothing *is* to be done any more.

Finishing a specification means ending the process of drafting it, finalizing a specification means ending the process of *refining* it into a state fit for formal adoption.

Answer (score 0):

### Work/Products gets "finished" - Projects get "finalized"

*Finalized* is not a synonym "finished" with different connotations. The words refer to related but distinct things.

For example, consider a project to create a software application:

The developers do their work, until they are "finished."

Then various other defined tasks within the project are done (testing, user acceptance, management sign-off, etc.). When all the required steps are complete, the project is "finalized."

Then imagine a serious flaw is discovered. It is clear that there is work to be done - the product is not "finished." But the project has been "finalized" - that does not change. (And the work to fix the flaw will probably be part of a new project.)